# How to notify devices for characteristic update?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my iOS app, I am using BLE so that devices can read the value of a characteristic from the peripheral device. And it's working. Now I want the peripheral device to be able to notify the other devices when the value of a characteristic changes. So when the other devices have their `DiscoveredPeripheral` callback, I have the code:

```
e.Peripheral.UpdatedNotificationState += Peripheral_UpdatedNotificationState;
e.Peripheral.SetNotifyValue(true, myCharacteristic);
```

This tells the framework that I want to be notified for updates on `myCharacteristic` from the peripheral device, right? But on the peripheral side, how do I actually notify the subscribed devices of an update? On Android, I would have to keep a list of all the connected devices and call `NotifyCharacteristicChanged` on each one. Is the process similar for iOS?

Note: I'm writing this app in Xamarin.iOS, but an answer in native iOS would work for me as I can translate it.

Comment: Pretty sure that you'll have to relay the update in some way. I don't think the notification can be a "broadcast".

Comment: What do you mean by "devices" and "other devices"? Is this iPhones or peripheral devvices?

Comment: When you have a group of devices (iPhones and Androids in my case) that want to connect via BLE, one of them becomes the peripheral device, and the rest are central devices. Comparing it to client-server architecture, peripheral is the server and central devices are the clients. I don't think it's relevant if the peripheral device is an iPhone or not, from my understanding at least. By "other devices" I mean the central (client) device that want to receive notifications from the peripheral (server) device.

Comment: In my Android app, I have to write to the `descriptor` of the characteristic to get notifications. Do I need to do the same in iOS? If so, how?